# Arcball camera inverting at 90 deg azimuth

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3, glm-math, arcball

I'm attempting to implement an arcball style camera. I use glm::lookAt to keep the camera pointed at a target, and then move it around the surface of a sphere using azimuth/inclination angles to rotate the view.

I'm running into an issue where the view gets flipped upside down when the azimuth approaches 90 degrees.

Here's the relevant code:

1. Get projection and view martrices.  Runs in the main loop

   ```
   void Visual::updateModelViewProjection()
   {
       model = glm::mat4();
       projection = glm::mat4();
       view = glm::mat4();

       projection = glm::perspective
           (
           (float)glm::radians(camera.Zoom),
           (float)width / height, // aspect ratio
           0.1f, // near clipping plane
           10000.0f // far clipping plane
           );

       view = glm::lookAt(camera.Position, camera.Target, camera.Up);
   }
   ```
2. Mouse move event, for camera rotation

   ```
   void Visual::cursor_position_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
   {
       if (leftMousePressed)
       {
          ...
       }

       if (rightMousePressed)
       {
           GLfloat xoffset = (xpos - cursorPrevX) / 4.0;
           GLfloat yoffset = (cursorPrevY - ypos) / 4.0;

           camera.inclination += yoffset;
           camera.azimuth -= xoffset;
           if (camera.inclination > 89.0f)
               camera.inclination = 89.0f;
           if (camera.inclination < 1.0f)
               camera.inclination = 1.0f;

           if (camera.azimuth > 359.0f)
               camera.azimuth = 359.0f;
           if (camera.azimuth < 1.0f)
               camera.azimuth = 1.0f;

           float radius = glm::distance(camera.Position, camera.Target);
           camera.Position[0] = camera.Target[0] + radius * cos(glm::radians(camera.azimuth)) * sin(glm::radians(camera.inclination));
           camera.Position[1] = camera.Target[1] + radius * sin(glm::radians(camera.azimuth)) * sin(glm::radians(camera.inclination));
           camera.Position[2] = camera.Target[2] + radius * cos(glm::radians(camera.inclination));

           camera.updateCameraVectors();
       }

       cursorPrevX = xpos;
       cursorPrevY = ypos;
   }
   ```
3. Calculate camera orientation vectors

   ```
   void updateCameraVectors()
   {
       Front = glm::normalize(Target-Position);
       Right = glm::rotate(glm::normalize(glm::cross(Front, {0.0, 1.0, 0.0})), glm::radians(90.0f), Front);
       Up = glm::normalize(glm::cross(Front, Right));
   }
   ```

I'm pretty sure it's related to the way I calculate my camera's right vector, but I cannot figure out how to compensate.

Has anyone run into this before?  Any suggestions?

Comment: In `Right` computation you take cross product of `Front` and `(0, 1, 0)` which is zero if `Front` is collinear to `(0, 1, 0)`. And normalizing zero vector could lead to strange behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [common mistake](https://stannum.io/blog/0UaG8R) to use `lookAt` for rotating the camera. You should not. The backward/right/up directions *are* the columns of your view matrix. If you already have them then you don't even need `lookAt`, which tries to redo some of your calculations. On the other hand, `lookAt` doesn't help you in finding those vectors in the first place.

Instead build the view matrix first as a composition of translations and rotations, and then extract those vectors from its columns:

```
void Visual::cursor_position_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{
    ...
    if (rightMousePressed)
    {
        GLfloat xoffset = (xpos - cursorPrevX) / 4.0;
        GLfloat yoffset = (cursorPrevY - ypos) / 4.0;

        camera.inclination = std::clamp(camera.inclination + yoffset, -90.f, 90.f);
        camera.azimuth = fmodf(camera.azimuth + xoffset, 360.f);

        view = glm::mat4();
        view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, camera.radius)); // add camera.radius to control the distance-from-target
        view = glm::rotate(view, glm::radians(camera.inclination + 90.f), glm::vec3(1.f,0.f,0.f));
        view = glm::rotate(view, glm::radians(camera.azimuth), glm::vec3(0.f,0.f,1.f));
        view = glm::translate(view, camera.Target);

        camera.Right = glm::column(view, 0);
        camera.Up = glm::column(view, 1);
        camera.Front = -glm::column(view, 2); // minus because OpenGL camera looks towards negative Z.
        camera.Position = glm::column(view, 3);

        view = glm::inverse(view);
    }
    ...
}
```

Then remove the code that calculates view and the direction vectors from `updateModelViewProjection` and `updateCameraVectors`.

Disclaimer: this code is untested. You might need to fix a minus sign somewhere, order of operations, or the conventions might mismatch (Z is up or Y is up, etc...).

Comment: Thank you! This is so much simpler. I am wondering though, what is the purpose of the glm::inverse at the end? It seems to work better without it, and I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything

Comment: @lmoyn: Right/Up/Backward/Position vectors in the world space are the columns of the matrix transforming *from camera space to world space* (assuming column-vectors). But the view matrix is typically meant to translate *from world space to camera space*. Hence the inverse: I first calculate the camera->world transform, then extract the vectors (this step is optional if you don't need them), then inverse the matrix to get the world->camera transform. If you say that it looks wrong, that's probably because I got the order of `glm::translates/rotates` wrong. Try reversing them.

Comment: I don't use glm -- one reason is that I prefer other libraries which use explicit order of matrix multiplication -- unlike glm where it's unclear if `glm::rotate(M, ...)` calculates the rotation matrix `R` whether it returns `M*R` or `R*M`. Even their documentation is vague in this regard. I assumed that it is the `R*M` that it does, if not then everything must be done in the reverse order.